# No results when I set sort filters

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm a newbie to Android and parse. I've uploaded some images to my parse back-end and want to display them in my app.

I know the images are there and are accessible since when I disable my filters, I get the results I want. I've reviewed my code and everything checks out, but, no results. What could I have overlooked?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_feed);

final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
Intent intent = getIntent();
final String activeUserName = intent.getStringExtra("username");

setTitle(activeUserName + "'s Feed");    

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Image");
//query.whereEqualTo("username", activeUserName);
//query.orderByDescending("createdAt");

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                         @Override
                         public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                           if (e == null) {
                             if (objects.size() > 0) {
                               for (ParseObject object : objects) {
                                 ParseFile file = (ParseFile) object.get("image");

                             file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                               @Override
                               public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                 if (e == null && data != null) {
                                   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

                                   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                                   imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                                   ));
                                   imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                                   linearLayout.addView(imageView);
                                 }
                               }
                             });
                           }
                         } else {
                           Toast.makeText(UserFeedActivity.this, activeUserName + " " + getString(R.string.feed_no_images), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         }
                       }
                     }
                   }
```

);
}

Comment: Triple check that your filters are correct.

Comment: Why aren't you getting the username with `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername()`?

Comment: @JakeT. I'm writing an Instagram clone. I need to load NOT my profile, but that of the user whose avatar I click on and whose username is then forwarded in the intent.

Comment: Oh. An active user would usually refer to the logged in user, not another user. Clean up those indentations so I can tell what's going on and I'll take another look. You may also want to post a screenshot of your parse dashboard with the classes and fields for the Image class.